# Chasing the long pause in JVM application

Tags: java, linux

On my production application running JVM (powered by JRuby). We are seeing a behaviour were in our Request take longer than usual to get a reply.

The average time that our application takes to reply back is around 95-100 ms...

(The application is **multithreaded** application)

Yet, there are instances where we are seeing an unexpectedly long time to reply back 300, 400, 1000, 2000ms and sometimes more than that? (2min)

We do make IO calls(Redis and Postgres which are running on different boxes) and we have timing(measured) for those calls. We have also been doing GC logging and logging which reflect where JVM might have halted but all those information on JVM logging shows that JVM is not the culprit.

I'm running out of options now...

```
- If, JVM is not an issue. 
- We don't do any disk write. So, I can safely rule out Disk latency.
- CPU usage seems very normal.
- Memory does not look like an issue.
- The instance is in on Google compute and they have not reported us any unusual Network jitter thus far
```

Here are the two request(logged on our ELK) that took more than a sec.
`Overall Time Taken:(1094.0) ms` and `Overall Time Taken:(1109.0) ms`

> 2018-03-02 18:34:27.093 W [19792:[Celluloid] PolicyRouter::Requ]
>   PolicyRouter -- Threshold Exceeded => Call
>   Id:dbf6dfd0-143e-4211-bc1a-23aba42fd024 | Event Name:reply | SIP
>   Method:INVITE | Overall Time Taken:(1094.0) ms | SEQ: 20296 |
>   REPLY_SEQ:20295 | IO Records: Redis (FETCH): ["(1.0) ms", "(0.0) ms"]
>   || Postgres (ROUTELINK): ["(1.0) ms"] || Postgres (FETCH DETAILS):
>   ["(5.0) ms"] || REDIS (Store): ["(1.0) ms", "(1.0) ms"] || Postgres
>   (Destination blocked): ["(1.0) ms"] || HTTP Call (LRN): ["(2.0) ms"]
>   || HTTP Call (LATA): ["(12.0) ms"] || HTTP Call (CIC): ["(2.0) ms"]
>
> 2018-03-02 18:34:27.086 W [19792:[Celluloid] PolicyRouter::Requ]
>   PolicyRouter -- Threshold Exceeded => Call
>   Id:eb262aaf-4ca2-4060-a4fc-1b56c1dabd73 | Event Name:reply | SIP
>   Method:INVITE | Overall Time Taken:(1109.0) ms | SEQ: 20296 |
>   REPLY_SEQ:20295 | IO Records: Redis (FETCH): ["(1.0) ms", "(0.0) ms"]
>   || Postgres (ROUTELINK): ["(2.0) ms"] || Postgres (FETCH DETAILS):
>   ["(6.0) ms"] || REDIS (Store): ["(1.0) ms", "(1.0) ms"] || Postgres
>   (Destination blocked): ["(1.0) ms"] || HTTP Call (LRN): ["(2.0) ms"]
>   || HTTP Call (LATA): ["(4.0) ms"]  ||  HTTP Call (CIC): ["(2.0) ms"]

And here the corresponding entry in the GC log for the same time...

**grep --color -r '18:34:2[8|7|6|5]' .**

```
./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:25.820+0000: 26497.392: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-03-01T18:34:25.820+0000: 26497.392: [ParNew: 201042K->13160K(224704K), 0.0265914 secs] 491098K->303230K(1535424K), 0.0267182 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]

./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:25.847+0000: 26497.419: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0282448 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000859 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:27.319+0000: 26498.891: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-03-01T18:34:27.319+0000: 26498.891: [ParNew: 200424K->13862K(224704K), 0.0230393 secs] 490494K->303938K(1535424K), 0.0231598 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]

./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:27.342+0000: 26498.915: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0243789 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001431 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:28.779+0000: 26500.351: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-03-01T18:34:28.779+0000: 26500.351: [ParNew: 201126K->13549K(224704K), 0.0275545 secs] 491202K->303816K(1535424K), 0.0276718 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

./gc.log:2018-03-01T18:34:28.807+0000: 26500.379: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0289318 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000772 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:26.062+0000: 112897.634: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014480 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001054 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.089+0000: 112898.661: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013859 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000981 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.117+0000: 112898.689: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014202 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000960 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.236+0000: 112898.808: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-03-02T18:34:27.236+0000: 112898.808: [ParNew: 200462K->14190K(224704K), 0.0253172 secs] 1136790K->950531K(1535424K), 0.0254408 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.261+0000: 112898.833: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0283838 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0015403 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.276+0000: 112898.848: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015471 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001604 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:27.280+0000: 112898.852: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013429 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001684 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:28.041+0000: 112899.613: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-03-02T18:34:28.041+0000: 112899.613: [ParNew: 201454K->13994K(224704K), 0.0253102 secs] 1137795K->950344K(1535424K), 0.0254327 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:28.067+0000: 112899.639: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0269445 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000977 seconds

./gc.log:2018-03-02T18:34:28.075+0000: 112899.647: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018988 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001296 seconds
```

JVM options.

```
-J-Xms1536M -J-Xmx1536M -J-Xss3M -J-Djruby.memory.max=1536M -J-Djruby.thread.pool.enabled=true -J-Djruby.compile.mode=FORCE -J-XX:NewRatio=3 -J-XX:NewSize=256M -J-XX:MaxNewSize=256M -J-XX:+UseParNewGC -J-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -J-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -J-XX:SurvivorRatio=5 -J-server -J-Xloggc:/home/deploy/gcLog/gc.log -J-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -J-XX:+PrintGCDetails -J-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -J-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -J-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1
```

Other details...

The Instance is **4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory** (located in Google Compute Instance)

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

The instance has no other user process running than the one mention above..

Other Theory I'm thinking on..

I have read Google Documentation... Where they mention that they do move there VM across. Can this be that ghost that I'm chasing?

Please ask do ask me any further question on this..

Can anyone out there please provide me with a pointer where do I look and what possible path should I follow?

I was thinking of doing running a `strace` but since this stuff happens so **randomly** that I'm hardly been able to do so thus far.

The script is running from past 2 days and I have noticed only 2 occurrence  of it.

Comment: You should profile the code and check the number of allocations you are making. Except for the big jump in time, the timing of the GC messages looks a little suspicious. Are you allocating huge colections anywhere by any chance?

Comment: My guess would be the GC. I have often seen long pauses on systems which have much memory (16-32G).

Comment: @lexicore I have already pasted the GC log details for that period.

Comment: @TheBeardedOne The problem is the problem only happen for a while and never happen again so random ..The code is been running for past 2 days and I found only these 2 entry .. that took 1 sec and above to reply back